# How can I split a row in SQL into separate, numbered rows?

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

(SQL flavor is Spark-native SQL) Say I have a row such as:

```
**userId** : String | **assignedEntities** : String
JOHN | "ENTITY_1,ENTITIY_2,...,ENTITY_100"
```

And I wanted to split this up into "chunked" lists of size 2, but with different keys to identify them:

```
**userId** | **assignedEntities**
JOHN_1 | "ENTITY_1,ENTITIY_2"
JOHN_2 | "ENTITY_2,ENTITY_3"
...
```

It's important to change the keys here to avoid a later collision, and I'm not sure how I could accomplish both things simply with something like `explode()`.

Any advice?

Note: assignedEntities is a string, but I'm comfortable enough with my regex magic to split it as needed (once I have a method to split it)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it:

```
select user_id, concat(entity_1 || ',' || entity_2)
union all
select user_id, concat(entity_2 || ',' || entity_3)
order by
user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Column "assignedEntities" can be split, and exploded with "posexplode" function:

```
val df = List(("JOHN", "ENTITY_1,ENTITY_2,ENTITY_3,ENTITY_4")).toDF("userId", "assignedEntities")

val splited = df.withColumn("assignedArray", split($"assignedEntities", ","))
val exploded = splited.select($"userId", posexplode($"assignedArray"))
val result = exploded.select(concat($"userId", lit("_"), $"pos".plus(1)).as("userId"), $"col".as("assignedEntities"))

result.show(false)
```

output:

```
+------+----------------+
|userId|assignedEntities|
+------+----------------+
|JOHN_1|ENTITY_1        |
|JOHN_2|ENTITY_2        |
|JOHN_3|ENTITY_3        |
|JOHN_4|ENTITY_4        |
+------+----------------+
```

In this example column split by ",". If you comfortable with regexp like you mentioned in note, use appropriate expression. Or custom UDF for split by pairs can be used instead of "split"